# Pydantic json value is empty on Custom Enum

Tags: python, enums, pydantic

I'm working with Pydantic And I want my Enums to also have docstring.

when I use `enum.Enum` The `CookingModel` works fine.

```
import enum
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError

class DocEnum(enum.Enum):
    """Enum with docstrings support"""

    def __new__(cls, value, doc=None):
        """add docstring to the member of Enum if exists

        Args:
            value: Enum member value
            doc: Enum member docstring, None if not exists
        """
        obj = str.__new__(cls)
        obj._value_ = value
        if doc:
            obj.__doc__ = doc
        return obj


class FruitEnum(str, enum.Enum):
    pear = 'pear'
    banana = 'banana'

class CookingModel(BaseModel):
    fruit: FruitEnum

a = CookingModel(fruit='banana')

a.json()
```

will return:
`{"fruit": "banana"}`

but when I change `enum.Enum` to `DocEnum`(so I can get docstrings).

```
class FruitEnum(str, DocEnum):
    pear = 'pear'
    banana = 'banana'
```

it will return:
`{"fruit": ""}`

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing `value` as second argument to `str.__new__` solve the problem.

```
import enum
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError

class DocEnum(enum.Enum):
    """Enum with docstrings support"""

    def __new__(cls, value, doc=None):
        """add docstring to the member of Enum if exists

        Args:
            value: Enum member value
            doc: Enum member docstring, None if not exists
        """
        obj = str.__new__(cls, value)
        obj._value_ = value
        if doc:
            obj.__doc__ = doc
        return obj


class FruitEnum(str, DocEnum):
    pear = 'pear', 'it's pear docstring'
    banana = 'banana'
```